# Vue 3 - How do i wrap a component in Vue with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, primevue

I'm trying to wrap a PrimeVue component (Calendar), change its style a bit, and then export it again.

Something like the following in react:

```
const WrappedCalendar: React.FC<CalendarProps> = (props)=> 
<div style={{background:'green'}}>
    <Calendar {...props}/>
</div>
```

however, I'm unable to do it since I keep getting constant typescript errors.
I've tried creating a component and Extending from primeVues Calendar but that also fails.

the following is a simple example of what I've tried, and even that doesn't work with typescript and behaves incorrectly.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import Calendar, { CalendarProps, CalendarSlots } from 'primevue/calendar';
import { defineProps, h, } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps<CalendarProps>()
const slots = defineSlots<CalendarSlots>() 
const CalendarFC = () => {
  return h(Calendar, props, slots)
}
</script>
<template>
  <div :style="{ background: 'green' }">
      <CalendarFC></CalendarFC>
  </div>
</template>
```

**is there any easy way to wrap a component so that the new component can be used with the same props / emits / slots as the original one and have the typescript behave identically?**

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code below, and it's working fine. The problem might be related to PrimeVue.

Alternatively, using JSX/TSX for this task would be more convenient. You can find more information on the [official Vue.js documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#jsx-tsx).

TestChild.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ testProp }}
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineSlots, defineProps } from 'vue';
import type { Props, Slots } from './shared.type.ts';

defineProps<Props>();
defineSlots<Slots>();
</script>
```

shared.type.ts

```js
export interface Props {
  testProp: string;
}
export interface Slots {
  default(): any;
}
```

TestParent.vue

```html
<template>
  <TestChildWrap />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineSlots, defineProps, h } from 'vue';
import TestChild from './TestChild.vue';
import type { Props, Slots } from './shared.type.ts';

const props = defineProps<Props>();
const slots = defineSlots<Slots>();

const TestChildWrap = () => {
  return h(TestChild, { ...props }, slots);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to get emits working as well?